# Youtube player options to display

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am creating a container for youtube video, which on hover scale to 2x, but the problem is that even if on 200px it is showing player options which sets in 100. Let me know how can I make my youtube player to popup with the options available for 200px.

Working Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/uu1rz6vp/

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.rect {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 2s, border-width 2s;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.rect:hover {  
  transform: scale(3);
  border-width: 1px;
}
.rect iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rect">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLUWTjL2IH0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="static-container">
  <iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLUWTjL2IH0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="static-container">
  <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLUWTjL2IH0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/uu1rz6vp/1/

CSS Transforms only scale the element, to change actual size, you have to set its `width` and `height` as below. I also update positioning values and add translate to make it center aligned.

```
.rect {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.rect:hover {       
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.rect {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s, border-width 2s;
  transform-origin: center;
}
.rect:hover {  
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.rect iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 96%;
  height: 96%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rect">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLUWTjL2IH0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="static-container">
  <iframe width="100" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLUWTjL2IH0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="static-container">
  <iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qLUWTjL2IH0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```